# Keep track of moves made in board game

Tags: scheme, mit-scheme

I'm working on creating a chess game in MIT Sceheme. I want to create a procedure that keeps track of the moves made by all the pieces.

Here is an example.
I make the rook move up 5 spaces. My next turn I want it to move back 5 spaces. The problem is, I don't know how to keep track of the piece i moves forward in the preceding turn - therefore i don't know how to move it back. when I can do currently is take the entire state of the board. I assume i need to use some type of mutation?

Comment: "My next turn I want it to move back 5 spaces" - that's probably not how you will define your move.. it's more like: "move the piece at c7 to c2". note: removed the AI tag.. no idea why you used it.

Comment: You don't have to use mutables, although they may be your best option.  I have two questions.  First, why do you need to retain your moves in order to make another move -- unless it's to handle a draw case?  Second, what are you currently using to store your board?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath you're correct. I'm passing a pair (cons source destination) to move a piece. I can reverse the pair to make it move back, but only certain pieces that were moved before can be reversed otherwise it will try to move a piece from an empty position to a full position.

Comment: @user1161318 I only need to retain my move to move it backwards by applying reverse to the pair. I need to keep track of piece that were moved before, so it doesn't try to move pieces that from an empty square to a occupied square  (as explained above).

Comment: Why are you doing anything special for a backwards move?  A move is a move, just treat it as such.  As for dealing with occupied spots, that's what the board state is for.  So given a board state and a prospective move, you have everything you need to decide if a move is legal and to accomplish it.  (make-move board move) would return a new board, and you can use this tail recursively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try keeping track of all previous moves in a list -- just `cons` on your most recent move (and symbol that tells you which piece performed the move) onto the move-log list and pass that along with your procedures.  If for some reason you need to find a recent move, it will be simple to search the list a few steps backward, and this would give you some added functionality if you wanted to track games.

If you would like to share some of your code, I will edit this answer with more specific details on implementation.

Comment: That would great if you could look at my code. I have multiple files though, so if you want me to send them, just drop me a line at kurtisphil@gmail.com

Comment: @Art:  Well, I was thinking more along the lines of you editing your post here the procedures you use to make moves, but if you want a post a link to a git repo, I might find time to glance over it.

Comment: looking at your comment history, I see you've taken 1901. This is actually related to 1901 so I'd rather not post the files in public